# How to find the transition matrix from basis $E$ to $E'$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Suppose there is a linear transformation $T$ on $\mathbb R^n$. And 
$$E=[\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2...\epsilon_n]$$and
$$E'=[\epsilon'_1,\epsilon'_2,...\epsilon'_n]$$
are two different basis of $\mathbb R^n$. And let $A$ and $A'$ respectively be $T$'s matrix under $E$ and $E'$.
Now,suppose what we know are $A$ and $A'$ but we have no knowledge of $E$ and $E'$.The question is how to find the transition matrix from $E$ to $E'$, say, a matrix $M$ such that $E'=EM$?
One obvious thing is that $$A'=M^{-1}AM$$
and thus $A$ and $A'$ are similar and they share the same eigenvalues. What's more, if they are diagonalizable, then we can find $P$ and $P'$ such that
$$A=P\Lambda P^{-1}$$
and
$$A'=P'\Lambda P'^{-1}$$
which yields
$$M=PP'^{-1}$$
But, if I'm not this lucky, say, $A$ and $A'$ are not diagonalizable (and I also wonder if it is possible for a basis?), then what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E'=EM$, $E$ is a basis , hence is a invertible matrix. $\Rightarrow M = E^{-1}E'$.

Suppose $A'$ is a invertible matrix , so is $A$.

$AE=A'E' \Rightarrow A'E'(AE)^{-1} = id = A'E'E^{-1}A^{-1} \Rightarrow (A')^{-1}A=E'E^{-1}=N$

Where $N$ satisfies $E'=NE$.

Comment: But we don't know $E$ and $E'$.Please note that what we know are only $A$ and $A'$.

Comment: If A is a invertible matrix , then it's easy to find M. If not , may not be avaliable to find M.

Comment: Could you please show more details? That's just where I'm stuck.

Comment: @Vim I edited my answer. Show the way to find left transition matrix N, but right transition matrix M is not easy to find.

Comment: Ah,, But to be honest, as far as I know the transition matrix is a right one and I've never seen the left transition. And by the way, since we prefer using column to represent vectors and writing the basis as $$E=[\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2...\epsilon_n]$$ I think the the matrix denoting a linear transformation should also be a "right multiplication" so that the partitioned matrix equation $$E'=[\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2...\epsilon_n]A$$ will make sense.